# Book about the normal distribution and multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, references, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have a problem concerning the normal distribution and multivariate normal distribution. Is there an entire textbook that focuses on these distributions?

Comment: What is your _question?_ Demands for full explanation are far too broad to be answered here: people have even written whole books on multivariate normal distributions.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate.yes your right I edit my question.

Comment: @Alecos Papadopoulos.do you have link for this handbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is "The Handbook of the Normal Distribution" by J.K. Patel & C.B. Read (1982) which is a focused reference for the Normal distribution.
The book mainly focus on the univariate case, but has a chapter dedicated to the bivariate case.

For the multivariate case,
Y. L. Tong (1990), "The Multivariate Normal Distribution".

Comment: .do you have link for this handbook?

Comment: Sure, and it is the 2nd edition as I can see http://books.google.gr/books/about/Handbook_of_the_Normal_Distribution_Seco.html?id=zoVLF0VF9UYC&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how deep you want to go, but one book I have used that delves very deeply into the multivariate normal (and associated distributions like the Wishart) is [Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory](https://www.bookdepository.com/Aspects-Multivariate-Statistical-Theory-Robb-J-Muirhead/9780471769859?ref=grid-view&qid=1606734430038&sr=1-26) by  Robb J. Muirhead